# App crashing on deleting a row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My table is used to list the rows from the core data. Everything works fine, I have used two types of data to load on the same table view. The data types change on account of the scope button change. Two scope buttons one displays completed tasks while other displays pending taks. I can search, update on the table. While only completed list of datas are editable and can be deleted, sometimes it works fine and sometimes it gives error as such,

```
Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of 
NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  *** -
[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds for empty array with 
userInfo (null)
```

The fetch result controller is initialised as,

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate{

if (self.fetchedResultsControl != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Here I am outside");

    return self.fetchedResultsControl;

}
```

The code to load the cell for tableview is as :

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell =(CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell=(CustomCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }

}

[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
```

}

And the update method called by the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is as;

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
[self.listingTable beginUpdates];
NSLog(@"Changed content");
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <  NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.listingTable insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.listingTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
```

}

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
NSLog(@"Changed content switch case");
UITableView *tableView = self.listingTable;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.listingTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.listingTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:(CustomCell *)[tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                atIndexPath:indexPath];

        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
      [self.listingTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.listingTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
NSLog(@"Changed Content");
[self.listingTable endUpdates];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any obvious errors but swapping out two logical tables in one tableview is a dangerous design because you have to be very careful that tableview knows that its logical table has been changed.

The error you are getting suggest that the tableview is configuring itself using one the index of one logical table but is actually accessing the array of the second logical table which is shorter.

Your immediate solution it to look closely at the methods like `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` to make sure that those update properly when you switched logical tables.

The best design solution is to use two separate tableviews with their own separate data source and then swap them out as needed.

Comment: I implemented log in the numberOfRowsInSection but the update is correct and so the number of rows before delete is 1 greater then after delete.

Comment: But also tried to print the managed object for unseen rows and so log gives message :<Memos: 0x71868e0> (entity: Memos; id: 0x7150c10 <xcoredata://A66DA972-7A6E-4572-BF10-178A6B3B70AD/Memos/p61> ; data: <fault>). But once the table is scrolled then the delete is possible. Is this bug of using two separate listings with the same fetchedresultscontroller and the same table view.

Comment: I can't say for certain your design is causing the problem but I think it likely.

Comment: Hello TechZen, I would like to change my design slightly such that I would like to create two entities one just for storing pending and completed and the other having complete list of items and then add a straight relationship to them.

Comment: That would work in the data model but if you try to display them both in the same table, you will get the same issues.

Comment: Well, finally I found the error. In  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section method, I simply used fetchedResultsController instead I should be using the getter method self.fetchedResultsController. Since a row is already a fetchedResultsController delegate is called but when deleting and listing in table view, it should get the update via the custom getter. Is this correct Techzen ?
 
 id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo =
 [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

Comment: @TechZen  Infact this is not the error? My app gets stuck oftenly again after. Now it gives some un predictable error as, _An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:. Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (8), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted)_

Comment: That error is usually caused by not freezing the tableview with `beginUpdate` before you try to insert or delete a new row. The error is caused because the number of sections and rows in the tableview is different from those returned by `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection`. You must freeze the tableview and make sure that you count of sections and rows stays in synch.